# Apex maps usage of keyset()

Tags: apex, collection

i have a method in that there is a map

```
Map<String,String> formSubmissionData = new Map<String,String>();

formSubmissionData.put('contact__c',contact.Id);
formSubmissionData.put('Enrollment__c',enrollment.Id);
formSubmission = insertFormSubmission(formSubmissionData);
```

from this map , loop on this map keyset and populate the form_submission record.

```
Form_Submission__c formSubmission = new Form_Submission__c( 
    Contact__c = formSubmissionData.get('contactId'),
    Enrollment__c = formSubmissionData.get('enrollmentId'),      
);*/
insert formSubmission;
```

i tried in this way i'm getting error , can any one help me?

```
Form_Submission__c formSubmission = new Form_Submission__c();
for( string fs:formSubmissionData.keyset())
{
  formSubmission.fs =formSubmissionData.get(fs);
 }
insert formSubmission;
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] your post to give the _exact, verbatim error_ and the line on which it occurs.

Comment: @madhukar please provide the error message, also I noticed that in your second block of codes you try to retrieve contact with the key 'contactId' but it should be 'contact__c', should return the value

Answer (score 4):

You can't refer to properties dynamically like that in Apex.

```
formSubmission.fs =formSubmissionData.get(fs);
```

If you want to place a value in the field whose name corresponds to the content of the variable `fs`, you must use the `put()` method.

```
formSubmission.put(fs, formSubmissionData.get(fs));
```

Comment: Invalid field formSubmissionRecordTypeId for Form_Submission__c , i am getting this error.

My concern here i need to use the keyset in the insertFormSubmission method from the above method which has map

Comment: @MadhukarReddy Please **[edit] your question** as requested above to give a clear and complete summary of your issue. I believe the answer here explains your problem, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use fs like this dynamically in apex.
`formSubmission.fs =formSubmissionData.get(fs);`
Use 
`formSubmission.put(fs,formSubmissionData.get(fs))`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first solution, you had an extra comma right before your closing paren `,)` for the constructor of you sObject `Form_Submission__c`. I have fixed it here:

```
Form_Submission__c formSubmission = new Form_Submission__c(Contact__c = formSubmissionData.get('contactId'),
                                                            Enrollment__c = formSubmissionData.get('enrollmentId'));
insert formSubmission;
```

Answer (score 0):

`formSubmission.fs =formSubmissionData.get(fs);`

In above code you are setting formSubmission.fs , if fs is a field in object Form_Submission__c then your code will work fine.

This explanation based on the code you have given plz update the full code to understand your exact problem.